# ASP.NET manually update updatepanel to show feedback in long function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a website that has a code-behind file and a separate class that has a function that takes a long time to complete.
What I want is to show some information to the visitor when the function passes a string.

I use a delegate to send a string back to the code-behind like this:

```
public event Feedback feedbackInfo;
public EventArgs e = null;
public delegate void Feedback(String message, bool info);
```

So in my function I can use `FeedbackInfo("message", true);` which is received by the code-behind function setFeedback:

```
public void example() {
    new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    crypto = new EncryptNoLibraries(@"C:\Users\Robbie\TestDES\New Microsoft Visio Drawing.vsdx", @"C:\Users\Robbie\TestDES\New Microsoft Visio Drawing encrypted.vsdx");
                    crypto.feedbackInfo += new EncryptNoLibraries.Feedback(setFeedback);

                    object[] allArgs = { EncryptNoLibraries.CryptType.ENCRYPT, lstSleutels };
                    object args = allArgs;
                    crypto.DoCryptFile(args);
                }).Start();
}

public void setFeedback(String message, bool info)
{
    if (info)
    {
        if (!infoCell.Visible)
        {
            errorCell.Visible = false;
            infoCell.Visible = true;
        }
        lblInfo.Text += String.Format("- {0}<br />", message);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!errorCell.Visible)
        {
            infoCell.Visible = false;
            errorCell.Visible = true;
        }
        lblError.Text += String.Format("- {0}<br />", message);
    }
}
```

This is my webpage:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home" Async="true" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DESEncryptie._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function updater() {
            __doPostBack('updatePanel', '');
        }
    </script>
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>DES encryptie/decryptie</h1>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                Kies simpelweg uw bestand. Vervolgens kiest u uw sleutel en de methode van encryptie of decryptie. Als laatste kiest u de taal waarmee u wilt werken (bijv. Java of .NET).
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h3>Start hier:</h3>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server" CssClass="tableStartHier">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>Bestand:</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="bestand" runat="server" on />
                        <i>(Probleem: bestandsnamen kunnen te lang zijn)</i>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:CheckBox ID="DES" runat="server" Checked="true" TextAlign="Left"
                        Text="DES" OnCheckedChanged="DES_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" /></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:CheckBox ID="ThreeDES" runat="server" Checked="false" TextAlign="Left"
                        Text="3DES" OnCheckedChanged="ThreeDES_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">Sleutel:</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow ID="sleutelDES" runat="server" Visible="true">
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSleutel" runat="server" placeholder="Geef een sleutel" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow ID="sleutelDrieDES1" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSleutel1" runat="server" placeholder="Geef sleutel 1" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow ID="sleutelDrieDES2" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSleutel2" runat="server" placeholder="Geef sleutel 2" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow ID="sleutelDrieDES3" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSleutel3" runat="server" placeholder="Geef sleutel 3" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>Taal:</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="taal" runat="server" Width="75px">
                            <asp:ListItem Text=".NET" Value=".NET" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text=".NET Libraries" Value=".NETLib" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Java Libraries" Value="Java" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:Button id="encrypteer" Text="Encrypteer" runat="server" OnClientClick="setInterval(updater, 2500);" OnClick="encrypteer_Click" ToolTip="Encrypteer uw bestand" /></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:Button id="decrypteer" runat="server" Text="Decrypteer" OnClick="decrypteer_Click" ToolTip="Decrypteer uw bestand" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="spinner" Visible="false">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgSpinner" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/spinner.gif"/>Even geduld.
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow ForeColor="Blue">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="infoCell" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2" Visible="false">
                        Informatieberichten tijdens het crypteren:<br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Text="" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow ForeColor="Red">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="errorCell" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2" Visible="false">
                        Foutberichten tijdens het crypteren:<br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

You can see I use a javascript to update my panel by postback every 2.5 seconds. The problem is that when the postback is triggered, the text in the label that should be update is lost.
Here are some images to illustrate. Before is how the page looks at first render and after is what is displayed after I push the encrypt button. Not all messages are displayed even after 2.5 seconds (they even disappear!).

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this was my fault, I found a solution.
I added two static string variables holding the messages so far.

```
private static String infoMessages = "", errorMessages = "";
public void setFeedback(String message, bool info)
{
    if (info)
    {
        if (!infoCell.Visible)
        {
            errorCell.Visible = false;
            infoCell.Visible = true;
        }
        infoMessages += String.Format("- {0}<br />", message);
        lblInfo.Text += infoMessages;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!errorCell.Visible)
        {
            infoCell.Visible = false;
            errorCell.Visible = true;
        }
        errorMessages += String.Format("- {0}<br />", message);
        lblError.Text += errorMessages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ASP .Net web page objects persist between posts. They are recreated and populated from your session store.

In my code, I have a background operation that is global to the app. I was able to use some static members in the class to relay progress of the background task to users.

I used the ASP timer to get the postbacks:

The Timer1_Tick method has no code in it. Just a comment stating the PageLoad did the work related to showing progress.

Your case will be a bit tougher, since you can have a background task for each browser instance.

If you use a static member dictionary, keyed by session id, the background process can update the dictionary entry and Page_Load can update the user's screen.

Then there's the problem of sessions coming and going. How do you clean up such a dictionary?

Also, remember IIS tends to shut down the whole web site process after 20 minutes of no http requests.

[And while I was typing my verbose answer, you seem to have found it yourself. Good show!]

Comment: Thanks for your contributions! I didn't know about the 20 minutes shut down for IIS